# Predicate application on an argument for Haskell pattern matching

Tags: haskell

I am developing a function in Haskell whose argument is a list of pairs. Recursively, this list will be split further until a base case is satisfied based on a predefined predicate.  Usually, for simpler data types e.g. lists , literals could be used for base case matching, such as '[ ]'. How can I apply pattern matching using a boolean predicate?

The only way I came up with is using if else statement. But apparently this would lead to obvious problem.

The pattern

```
pure_instances [(_,_)] = True
pure_instances ((c1,_):(c2,attrs):xs) = (c1 == c2) && (pure_instances ((c2,attrs):xs))
```

The method

```
build_tree list  = if (pure_instances list) then (Leaf get_label list) else (build_tree list) 
build_ tree list = ...
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the "obvious" problem is. Your code doesn't make sense (`pure_instances` isn't fully applied in `build_tree`), so it's hard to figure out what the problem is, or what you are asking.

Comment: Do you know about guards?

Comment: @ReidBatron Thank you for your clue , it inspired me !

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for guards? (thanks Reid Barton)

```
build_tree list
    | pure_instances list = Leaf get_label list
    | otherwise           = build_tree list
```

The infinite loop when `pure_instances` returns `False` is another matter...